# warnings: comparison between pointer and integer, passing argument 1 of ‘read’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c++, c, pointers

when compiling a program named Online_ana.c (by running a makefile) with following lines:

```
******#define FIFO1 (getenv("fifo1"))******
FILE *fifoFile;

54 : if ((fifoFile = fopen((FIFO1!=NULL) ? FIFO1 : "fifo1", O_RDONLY)) == -1)

153 : if ((read(fifoFile, &BufferHeader, sizeof(struct event_header))) != sizeof(struct event_header))

168 : if ((read(fifoFile, &MyBuffer[cnt], 4*BufferHeader.n_sca)) != 4*BufferHeader.n_sca)

189 : if ((read(fifoFile, &MyBuffer[cnt], 2*(BufferHeader.n_adc+BufferHeader.n_tdc+BufferHeader.n_pcos))) != 2*(BufferHeader.n_adc+BufferHeader.n_tdc+BufferHeader.n_pcos))


I encountered such warnings:

Online_ana.c:**54**:69: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
Online_ana.c: In function ‘GetBufferFromFifo’:
Online_ana.c:**153**:52: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:361:16: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
Online_ana.c:**168**:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:361:16: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
Online_ana.c:**189**:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘read’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/include/unistd.h:361:16: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct FILE *’
```

What is wrong? Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Mostly the warnings are because you pass a `FILE*` (a pointer) to a function that expects an integer argument. As for the warning with [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) it's because compare a pointer (`FILE*`) with an integer (`-1`).

In other words, you are mixing two different I/O systems.

Either you should use the POSIX function like [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), or you use the C functions [`fopen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) and [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread). Don't mix.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is all written as if you're working with UNIX file descriptors, not standard I/O file handles. If you want to go that way, change `fopen()` to `open()`, and change the declaration of `fifoFile` from a `FILE *` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using fopen() for opening a file which is a standard library function and this will give you a file pointer associated with the stream. 
On the other hand you are using read() which is a system call that takes file descriptor as its first input which is an integer.

Important thing is - The mode of the stream must be compatible with the mode of the file descriptor.

Although, it is also possible to convert FILE* to file descriptor(fd) using int fileno(FILE *stream) found in stdio.h